# Cleaner way to find all indices of same value in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I have a textfile like so

```
NameOne,2,3,3
NameTwo,1,0,2
```

I want to find the indices of the max value in each line in Scala. So the output of this would be

```
NameOne,1,2
NameTwo,2
```

I'm currently using the function below to do this but I can't seem to find a simple way to do this without a for loop and I'm wondering if there is a better method out there.

```
def findIndices(movieRatings: String): (String) = {
    val tokens = movieRatings.split(",", -1)
    val movie = tokens(0)
    val ratings = tokens.slice(1, tokens.size)
    val max = ratings.max
    var indices = ArrayBuffer[Int]()

    for (i<-0 until ratings.length) {
        if (ratings(i) == max) {
            indices += (i+1)
        }
    }

    return movie + "," + indices.mkString(",")

}
```

This function is called as so:

```
val output = textFile.map(findIndices).saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```

Just starting to learn Scala so any advice would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your code doesn't actually produce the expected result from your example input. I'm going to assume that the example given is the correct result.

```
def findIndices(movieRatings :String) :String = {
  val Array(movie, ratings @_*) = movieRatings.split(",", -1)
  val mx = ratings.maxOption  //Scala 2.13.x
  ratings.indices
         .filter(x => mx.contains(ratings(x)))
         .mkString(s"$movie,",",","")
}
```

Note that this doesn't address some of the shortcomings of your algorithm:

- No comma allowed in movie name.
- Only works for ratings from 0 to 9. No spaces allowed.

testing:

```
List("AA"
  ,"BB,"
  ,"CC,5"
  ,"DD,2,5"
  ,"EE,2,5, 9,11,5"
  ,"a,b,2,7").map(findIndices)

//res0: List[String] = List(AA,    <-no ratings
//                        , BB,0   <-comma, no ratings
//                        , CC,0   <-one rating
//                        , DD,1   <-two ratings
//                        , EE,1,4 <-" 9" and "11" under valued
//                        , a,0    <-comma in name error
//                        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zipWithIndex` and use `filter`:

```
ratings.zipWithIndex
  .filter { case(_, value) => value == max }
  .map { case(index, _) => index }
```